# Vaadin: Disable Copilot ("Double shift" function)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin

Is there a way to disable Copilot in development mode?

I know about setting `vaadin.devmode.devTools.enabled=false` in `application.properties` but this will only initially remove the icon on the bottom right. Once I hit "double shift" the icon reappears and switches to the component inspection mode.

It's really annoying that the browser enters this mode when I hit shift two times accidentally (or Shift+Space).

Comment: Update to the latest version

Comment: @ollitietavainen Okay, I was on 24.3.4 and had to update to 24.3.5. Now it is gone but I can't activate it again either (neither double shift nor the icon at the bottom right). Is that feature gone for good now?

Comment: @LordM-Cube I'm not sure if it already works (has been released), but the it's supposed to be shift+(ctrl+ctrl) on Windows or shift+(cmd+cmd) on Mac